# Using multiple values for single variable in a loop

Tags: bash, redhat

I have a small loop problem as below.

I have 3 different values to be used while running the same script -

```
va1="some-value1"
va2="some-value2"
va3="some-value3"
```

Now I want to use these three variable values to be used for running the same command, like -

```
while (i=0,i<=3,i++)
do
bin/java -s (run something with $var);
done
```

Now I want $var taking the value of var1, var2 and var3 each time it runs,

so can someone please tell me how do we achieve the above?

I tried doing -

```
for $1 $2 $3

do
case 1
case 2
case 3
done
```

OR

```
while read a b c
do
<code assumed to have loop iteration>
done <<< $(command)
```

But it isnt working as expected... Would really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the 'in' part of the syntax:

```
for var in $va1 $va2 $va3
do 
    command $var
done
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while ((i=0,i<=3,i++))
do
eval bin/java -s \$var$i
done
```

This is a great example of how to use `eval`. Note that 1. the value of $i is seen by the shell has it scans the line. Then because $var is escaped like `\$var`, it is not
'make visible' in the first scan. 2. `Eval` forces a 2nd scan of the cmd-line, so it sees $var1 or whatever, and that value is substituted into the command-line for execution.

Comment: Aack, don't use `eval` unless you really need to, as it is evil.  Indirect expansion can do the trick here, without risking the problems `eval` can introduce.

Comment: Definitely worth considering if there is any possibility that user inserts naughty code for evaling. Personally, I've only read about that happening, but I only load boring databases ;-) good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indirect variable expansion with `${!...}`:

```
va1="some-value1"
va2="some-value2"
va3="some-value3"
for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do
    varname="va$i"
    echo "$varname = ${!varname}"
done
```

This prints:

```
va1 = some-value1
va2 = some-value2
va3 = some-value3
```